# Pandas DataFrame update one column using another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a two-column DataFrame `df`, its columns are `phone` and `label`, which `label` can only be 0 or 1.
Here is an example:

```
phone  label
   a       0
   b       1
   a       1
   a       0
   c       0
   b       0
```

What I want to do is to calculate the number of '1' of each type of 'phone' and using the number replaces the 'phone' column
What i come with up is `groupby`, but i am not familiar with it

The answer should be:

```
Count the number of each 'phone'
phone    count
   a         1
   b         1
   c         0

replace the 'phone' with 'count' in the original table
phone
   1
   1
   1
   1
   0
   1
```

Comment: You want to find no. of rows in 'phone' given label==1 ??

Comment: Do you want: `df.groupby['phone'].sum()`?

Comment: But how can i replace the 'phone' with the 'sum'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking into account that the `label` column  can only have `0` or `1`, you can use [.trasnform('sum')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) method:

```
In [4]: df.label = df.groupby('phone')['label'].transform('sum')

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  phone  label
0     a      1
1     b      1
2     a      1
3     a      1
4     c      0
5     b      1
```

Explanation:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  phone  label
0     a      0
1     b      1
2     a      1
3     a      0
4     c      0
5     b      0

In [3]: df.groupby('phone')['label'].transform('sum')
Out[3]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and group data in pandas. For your case it would look

assume data is

```
  phone  label
0     a      0
1     b      1
2     a      1
3     a      1
4     c      1
5     d      1
6     a      0
7     c      0
8     b      0

df.groupby(['phone','label'])['label'].count()
phone  label
a      0        2
       1        2
b      0        1
       1        1
c      0        1
       1        1
d      1        1
```

If you require group count of `phones` given `label==1` then do this -

```
#first filter to get only label==1 rows
phone_rows_label_one_df = df[df.label==1]

#then do groupby
phone_rows_label_one_df.groupby(['phone'])['label'].count()

phone
a    2
b    1
c    1
d    1
```

To get `count` as a new column in the dataframe do this

```
phone_rows_label_one_df.groupby(['phone'])['label'].count().reset_index(name='count')
  phone  count
0     a      2
1     b      1
2     c      1
3     d      1
```

Comment: Actually, i want to find out the No. of rows of each type of 'phone' given label == 1.

Comment: How can i replace the 'phone' in the original table with the count?

Comment: Thanks for that, but you can see my example above, i don't want a new column,just replace in the original table